# Re autenticar en facebook con unity c#

Tags: c#, unity3d, facebook-api

El problema que tengo es en teoría simple, pero no he encontrado la forma de solucionarlo.

Puedo acceder a FB con unity, postear, ver y usar la información que necesito, toda esa parte funciona bien, toda la información que uso la guardo en un archivo local en el teléfono.

Al eliminar la aplicación (desinstalarla) y volverla a instalar e intentar iniciar sesión de nuevo me aparece un error, ya que la sesión por medio de la aplicación ya se ha permitido.

Alguien podría ayudarme a decir como puedo "re-autenticar" la sesión de FB.

**Actualización 14 jul. a las 20:16**

El error que tenia era que me decía que el "Key Hashes" no coincidía con el ninguna aplicación, la solución a ese problema es bastante simple, solo tome el hash key que me devolvía la app y lo agregue en los "Key Hashes" de FB, después de eso se soluciono el problema en todos los dispositivos.

El unico "problema" es distinguir entre la "I" mayúscula y la "L" minúscula.

Pero solo deben tomar ese "Key Hash" y con eso se soluciona, al parecer solo se ocupa el "Key Hash" de unity para acceder la primera vez, y las demás se requiere el de la app.

Comment: Podrias mostrar el error que te aparece. Y mostrar el codigo con el que consumes la api de facebook

Answer (score 1):

El error que tenia era que me decía que el "Key Hashes" no coincidía con el ninguna aplicación, la solución a ese problema es bastante simple, solo tome el hash key que me devolvía la app y lo agregue en los "Key Hashes" de FB, después de eso se soluciono el problema en todos los dispositivos.

El unico "problema" es distinguir entre la "I" mayúscula y la "L" minúscula.

Pero solo deben tomar ese "Key Hash" y con eso se soluciona, al parecer solo se ocupa el "Key Hash" de unity para acceder la primera vez, y las demás se requiere el de la app.